# How do i define a setter for a list with an index or slicing?

Tags: python-3.x, properties, setter

With the property and setter decorator I can define getter and setter functions. This is fine for primitives but how do I index a collection or a numpy array?
Setting values seems to work with an index, but the setter function doesn't get called. Otherwise the print function in the minimal example would be executed.

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self._arr = [0, 1, 2]

    @property
    def arr(self):
        return self._arr

    @arr.setter
    def arr(self, value):
        print("new value set")  # I want this to be executed
        self._arr = value


data = Data()

print(data.arr)  # prints [0, 1, 2]
data.arr[2] = 5
print(data.arr)  # prints [0, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a secondary class that wraps the indexing/slicing functions onto that object type.

(Credit: inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70511520/1717003) answer)

```
class SubData():
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self._arr = arr.copy()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print("SubData getter")
        return self._arr[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        print("SubData setter")
        self._arr[index] = value
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._arr)

class Data():
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self._arr = SubData(vals)

    @property 
    def arr(self):
        print("Data getter")
        return self._arr
    
    @arr.setter
    def arr(self, value):
        print("Data setter")
        self._arr = value

#--main--
        
>a = Data([1,2,3])

>a.arr[2]=5
Data getter
SubData setter

>print(a.arr)
Data getter
[1, 2, 5]
```

For more complex behavior such as a 2D array, you would need to check the instance of the index (ie, `a.arr[2,5]` passes a tuple to index). This you wouldn't have to implement the subclass if you used something like a numpy array which implements these indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this just for one list of your class instance you can do this *in a way* by using the `__set_item__` and `__get_item__` dunder methods of the class:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self._arr = [0, 1, 2]

    @property
    def arr(self):
        return self._arr

    @arr.setter
    def arr(self, value):
        print("new inner list set")
        self._arr = value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print("new value set")
        self._arr[key] =  value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._arr[key]

data = Data()

print(data.arr)

data[2] = 5
print(data.arr) 

data.arr = [42, 43]
print(data.arr)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]

new value set        # by    data[2] = 5           using __set_item__
[0, 1, 5]

new inner list set   # by    data.arr = [42, 43]   using @arr.setter
[42, 43]
```

This would only work for one list member though, because the `__set_item__` are working on the class instance itself, not the list that is a member of the class instance.

Comment: Yes, but as you already described `__set_item__` refers to the class instance. Thus, as far as I see, it doesn't solve any problem because it breaks as soon as I have more than one property. This way I only redefine the normal functionality of a list which makes the definition of a new class obsolete. 
Isn't there a more elegant way than defining a `set_arr` method?