# How to use indexing with the @property decorator

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator

I'm trying to change certain indices of a class attribute that is a matrix with python decorators. The problem is that I don't know how to specify the index with the setter method. My code is something like this:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, N, M):
        self.large_matrix = np.zeros(N, M)
        self.some_set = [1,2,3]
    
    @property
    def matrix(self):
        return self.large_matrix[:,self.some_set]
    
    @matrix.setter
    def matrix(self,value):
        self.large_matrix[:,self.some_set] = value
```

With this class I want to change certain values of the large matrix through accessing the smaller matrix, for example:

```
self.matrix[index] = value
```

This doesn't work though. The code runs without raising errors but the values in the large matrix don't change.
Conversely, if I type

```
self.matrix = value
```

It works just fine. I should also mention that it's crucial to have the decorators, as the attribute *self.someset* changes sometimes. Therefore, I want the large matrix to remain untouched at those indices I'm not working on, but I do need to store them in the class for later reference.

One solution I found is the following:

```
m = self.matrix.copy()
m[index] = value
self.matrix = m
```

This works, but I presume the code becomes much slower (which is a factor) and it's laborious to change this everywhere in the code. To clarify; the matrix needs to be accessed within the class. Is there any solution to changing the *@matrix.setter* decorator and method such that the code remains efficient and I don't have to change the code everywhere?

Comment: if you put `print()` in both functions then you should see that `matrix[index] = value` runs `getter`, not `setter` - to get `matrix` - and later it runs `[4]` on value from `getter`. The only idea is to use `__getitme__`, `__setitem__` instead of `matrix`

Comment: I'm rather confused by your example code since none of it is using attribute notation which is where properties come in. Are you creating an instance of `A` with something like `a = A(5,5)` and all the references to `matrix` in your example are really `a.matrix`? Please make your example into a [mcve].

Comment: @blckknght I changed it now, apologies for the unclarity. Just to clarify; in the example, I call the matrix within the same class to perform computations.

Answer (score 2):

If you put `print()` in both functions then you should see that `matrix[index] = value` runs `getter`, not `setter`. It runs `getter` to get `matrix` and later it runs `[4]` on value from `getter`. But `getter` uses index `[:,self.some_set]` so it copies data from `large_matrix` and returns new `array` which has no access to data in original `array`.

The only idea is to create new class which will get `large_matrix`  and `some_set` and it will work with this sub matrix. And original `matrix()` will get this class or set value in all items in this matrix

```
import numpy as np

class SubMatrix():
    def __init__(self, matrix, some_set):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.some_set = some_set

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print('getitem:', index)
        return self.matrix[index, self.some_set]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        print('setitem:', index, value)
        self.matrix[index, self.some_set] = value


class A():
    def __init__(self, N, M):
        self.large_matrix = np.zeros((N, M))
        self.some_set = [1,2,3]
        self.sub_matrix = SubMatrix(self.large_matrix, self.some_set)

    @property
    def matrix(self):
        print('getter')
        return self.sub_matrix
    
    @matrix.setter
    def matrix(self, value):
        print('setter')
        self.sub_matrix[:] = value

# --- main ---

m = A(5, 5)

print(">>> m.matrix[4] = 1")
m.matrix[4] = 1
print(m.large_matrix)
print('---')

print(">>> m.matrix = 1")
m.matrix = 1
print(m.large_matrix)
print('---')

print(">>> m.matrix[1] = [4,3,2]")
m.matrix[1] = [4,3,2]
print(m.large_matrix)
print('---')

print(">>> m.matrix[2:4] = [1,2,3]")
m.matrix[2:4] = [1,2,3]
print(m.large_matrix)
print('---')

print(">>> m.matrix[1]")
print(m.matrix[1])
print('---')
```

Result:

```
>>> m.matrix[4] = 1
getter
setitem: 4 1
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
---
>>> m.matrix = 1
setter
setitem: slice(None, None, None) 1
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
---
>>> m.matrix[1] = [4,3,2]
getter
setitem: 1 [4, 3, 2]
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 4. 3. 2. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
---
>>> m.matrix[2:4] = [1,2,3]
getter
setitem: slice(2, 4, None) [1, 2, 3]
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 4. 3. 2. 0.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 0.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
---
>>> m.matrix[1]
getter
getitem: 1
[4. 3. 2.]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you would use multidimensional `index` in `matrix` like

```
m.matrix[2:4,2] = [9]
```

then it would use

```
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        print('setitem:', index, value)
        if isinstance(index, tuple):
            self.matrix[index] = value   # ie. [2:4, 2]
        else:
            self.matrix[index, self.some_set] = value   # [2:4]
```

but this uses indexes for `large_matrix`, not in `matrix`.

---

```
print(">>> m.matrix[2:4,2] = [1,2,3]")
m.matrix[2:4,2] = [9]
print(m.large_matrix)
print('---')
```

Result:

```
>>> m.matrix[2:4] = [1,2,3]
getter
setitem: (slice(2, 4, None), 2) [9]
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 4. 3. 2. 0.]
 [0. 1. 9. 3. 0.]
 [0. 1. 9. 3. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
---
```

To use own indexes in `Matrix` it would need more complex code which recalculate indexes.

Comment: Great this seems to work, thanks!